# Ubuntu 15.04 hang when boot virtualbox Centos 6

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, 15.04

I have a freshly ubuntu 15.04 64 bit.
A virtual box 4.3.26 r98988.
And this image http://repo.scalefactory.com/vagrant/centos-6-x86_64-20.box
Now everytime I try to boot the VM, my laptop hang. 
Here is the bug report I get every time the laptop start after the first time get that issue: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10883069/